# Creating a barplot from an s3 constructor

Tags: r

I have most of this s3 constructor assignment working, thanks to stackoverflow contributors, but now I'm having issues creating a barplot of the information:

My constructor and variables are currently:

```
# Create constructor
ChlorReads <- function(theid, thename, thegender, theldl, thehdl, thetrigl) {
  x <- list(id=theid, name=thename, gender=thegender, ldl=theldl, hdl=thehdl, trigl=thetrigl)
  class(x) = "Patient"
  return(x)
}

# Prints the patient information (one item in the list)
print.Patient = function(x, ...){

  cat("ID: ", x$id, " Name: ", x$name, " Gender: ", x$gender,
      "\nLDL: ", x$ldl, " HDL: ", x$hdl, " Triglycerides: ", x$trigl,"\n", sep="")

}

# Input p1
p1 <- ChlorReads(9876, "Virgil", "M", 248, 45, 148)
```

I want to ultimately plot(p1), so I'm trying to create another function that allows me to create a table that looks like the following image:

[image: cholesterol barplot]

I currently have:

```
plot.Patient = function(x, ...) {
  counts <- table(x$ldl,x$hdl,x$trigl)
  barplot(counts, main="Chloresterol Readings")
}
```

But the table isn't working. I get the following error:  Error in barplot.default(counts, main = "Chloresterol Readings") : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values (height) that feed into the barplot function must be in vector or matrix form. This means that your object 'counts' is incorrect. See barplot documentation:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html

Comment: So if I turn those three variables into a vector/matrix, then it should fix my issue?

Comment: Can you provide some of the data?

Comment: Tried it and you were right. Thank you for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this, the code below created output similar to the example image posted above.

`plot.Patient = function(x, ...) {
  counts <- c(x$ldl,x$hdl,x$trigl)
  barplot(counts, main="Chloresterol Readings", xlab = c("Name: ", x$name), names.arg = c("LDL", "HDL", "Triglycerides"))
}`